# django and row sql

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x

What is the best way to import sql to python code:
I use django, but sometimes I write row sql, and sometimes this code is big. My question is how can I import examle.sql to my code.py

example.sql:

```
SELECT id FROM users_user
```

code.py:

```
row_sql = <this string> 

user_ids = RowSqlManager(row_sql).execute()
```

if I name my example.sql with name example.py it is easy, but I want separate python code and sql. Is there to do it? Or it is better to rename  example.sql to example.py